# Large MySQL Table - Index Breaking Down

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, partitioning

I have a ~100GB MySQL table with nearly 1 billion rows.  It only has 8 columns, one of which being an indexed DateTime that's used for most of the lookups via thinly sliced "BETWEEN" queries.

Previously my index on this column worked great... but as the table continued to grow, suddenly the index just stopped working.  Now EXPLAIN shows "using filesort" on all queries, and I've raised all applicable my.conf values for memory pools to no avail.

Is there a max on what a key can handle?  Would something like partitioning resolve this?

Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How many rows in the table? What engine are you using? InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: I said in the first sentence - nearly 1 billion rows.  And it's MyISAM.  Thanks!

Comment: Does your index fit in memory? Show your table status and 'key_buffer_size'

Comment: Have you tried to perform an OPTIMIZE operation on the table? Maybe the indexes need to be sorted. Perhaps you changed something in your queries? Added an ORDER BY clause that affects the query plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able, stop mysql server, and then go to your data folder and execute

```
myisamchk -r <table_name>
```

or

```
myisamchk -r -v -f <table_name>
```

that should repair your table. You can also try with

```
REPAIR TABLE <table_name>
```

more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) and  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html)

Comment: Wow, it really was that easy - I can't believe I didn't try that.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may try to force index usage by hints. 
Checkout  [the mysql page explaining the index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html). A really quick example is;

```
SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index)
  WHERE col1 BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```

But I don't think that is your main problem. To foresee the problems you may have in the future, I strongly advice you to carefully read the  [MySQL Resource Limits Excerpt](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-reslimits-excerpt-5.1-en.pdf)

In some point it states that;

```
If you do encounter a full-table error, there are several reasons why it might have occurred: 
...
You are using MyISAM tables on an operating system that supports files only up to 2GB in size and you have hit this limit for the data file or index file.
```

Seems like that is not the case for you. But you may consider some possibilities at this point.

I also strongly advice you to make a quick search for the keyword 'myisampack'.